# Turning off plus/minus sign on specific TreeView nodes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` control for which I would like to turn off the plus/minus sign for specific child TreeNode objects. I know I can do this at the entire TreeView level using the `TreeView.ShowPlusMinus` property, but I'm wondering if I can hide the signs only for selected TreeNode objects.

Comment: Do you mean **without** removing the nodes?

Comment: @jp2code: Nodes are loaded dynamically by reading data from a web-service. Before each node is loaded into the tree I want to check if it should be a non-collapsible node, in which case I would want to disable the plus/minus sign (separately I would also put the node into expanded mode and disable the normal double-click expand/collapse behavior). After the node is added to the tree I do not need to adjust the plus/minus before again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, the Windows Forms [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx) class wraps the native [tree view control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760017%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and that control only supports showing or hiding the plus/minus signs globally.

That's because, internally, that flag maps to the [TVS_HASBUTTONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760013%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#TVS_HASBUTTONS) control style, which of course affects the whole control and not individual items.

To my knowledge, the only way to achieve what you want is to handle the [DrawNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.asp) event and [render everything yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003459/c-treeview-owner-drawing-with-ownerdrawtext-and-the-weird-black-highlighting-wh).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit above, you should override your TreeView's BeforeCollapse event to cancel the collapse if it is a non-collapsible node:

```
private void treeView1_BeforeCollapse(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e) {
  MyParameter myP = e.Node.Tag as MyParameter;
  if (myP != null) {
    if (myP.Type == MyParameterType.NonCollapsible) {
      e.Cancel = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized that my comment may have been slightly misleading. Instead of saying "disable" the plus/minus sign I should have said "hide". Basically I want to disable both the expand/collapse behavior and hide the plus/minus sign so that it is clear to the user that the node cannot be collapsed. The key thing I do not know how to do is to hide the plus/minus sign.

Comment: I don't think that is possible with the built in control. If you want to go *off axis*, you will have to **roll your own**.

Answer (score 0):

Each TreeViewItem (TVITEM)  has an cChildren member.
If 0 the plusminus sign is hidden. if 1, the + sign is shown.

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Dont forget the TVIF_CHILDREN flag.

I answer, because I searched the the same question and found no answer.

Answer (score 0):

To remove plus/minus sign `setLoadOnDemand` to false;

```
Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTreeNode Node = new Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTreeNode();
Node.LoadedOnDemand = false;
```

Comment: The question is about win forms (System.Windows.Forms.TreeView) and not telerik. Your post is not an answer to the question.